# Problem with finding the efficient capital market line formula, getting negative variance

Tags: variance, covariance-matrix, weights

So my goal is to write the Capital Market line formula considering this data:
$\[
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \text{Stock 1} & \text{Stock 2} & \text{Probability} \\
  \hline
  -15\% & -20\% & 20\% \\
  15\% & 30\% & 30\% \\
  5\% & 15\% & 50\% \\
  \hline
\end{array}
\]
$
with Covariance(1,2)=1,83% and a risk free asset rf=0,035

I want to use the method using Tangency portfolio to deduce the CML formula, but my problem is that I find negative variances for the tangency portfolio...

Here's what I did so far:
To define the CML, I want to use this formula: µp=((µt-rf)/σt)*σp+rf
Now I'm trying to get µt and σt. To do so, first I'm calulating means and variances for each stock:
$\[
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  & \text{Stock 1} & \text{Stock 2} \\
  \hline
  \mu & 0.045 & 0.125 \\
  \sigma^2 & 0.0108 & 0.0306 \\
  \hline
\end{array}
\]$

And then I write the covariance variance matrix such as: $\[
\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
  0.0108 & 0.0183 \\
  0.0183 & 0.0306
\end{bmatrix}
\]$

And solve for Z=Σ^-1*(µ-rf) and get
$\[
Z = \begin{bmatrix}
  304.08 \\
  -178.91
\end{bmatrix}
\]$
from where I get those weights using w=zi/Sum(zi) $\[
W = \begin{bmatrix}
  2,42 \\
  -1,42
\end{bmatrix}
\]$

But when I try to get σ^2 of the tangency portfolio using WTΣW, I get σ^2=-8,2128e-4.... I really don't get what I did wrong.

Comment: First off all I think that your $\mu_1$ is off. It should be $\mu_1 = 0.04$ if I did not make any mistakes in my calculations.
Your given covariance seems to be a little weird.  The variance with my calculations are $Var_1 = 0.0109$ and $Var_2 = 0.030625$. Using Cauchy-Schwarz you get an upper bound: $Cov_{1,2} \leq \sqrt{(Var_1 * Var_2)} \approx 1.827 \%$. This explains the results close to 0 (yet negative).

Answer (score 1):

with the inputs you provided the result is negative. could it be possible that what you call *Covariance(1,2)* $=1.83\%$ is actually the correlation coefficient of Stock $1$ and Stock $2$ ?

Pretty much the only extra step you'd have to do if the above is true, is to compute the covariance via $Cov(1,2) = \rho\times\sigma_1\times\sigma_2$

doing so, the final result is positive. let me know if you want to see all the calculations.

hope this helps